# Java: Printwriter works almost perfectly, but inserts a few strange characters... Why is this happening?

Tags: java

I'm simply working on a homework program where I am using `FileOutputStream` to write some strings to a file. While it is working for the most part, for some reason the program keeps inserting some strange characters in the beginning of the file, with the rest of the file looking like it should. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out what's going on here.

So this is the code I have in the main class:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ChetSpalsky
 */
public class Writer {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    CarPlate carPlate1 = new CarPlate();
    carPlate1.setNumber("1098463");
    carPlate1.setState("CA");
    carPlate1.setColor("Blue");

    CarPlate carPlate2 = new CarPlate();
    carPlate2.setNumber("6371849");
    carPlate2.setState("MA");
    carPlate2.setColor("Red");

    CarPlate carPlate3 = new CarPlate();
    carPlate3.setNumber("5738402");
    carPlate3.setState("AZ");
    carPlate3.setColor("Green");

    String writeCarPlate1 = (carPlate1.getNumber() + " " + carPlate1.getState() + " " + carPlate1.getColor());
    String writeCarPlate2 = (carPlate2.getNumber() + " " + carPlate2.getState() + " " + carPlate2.getColor());
    String writeCarPlate3 = (carPlate3.getNumber() + " " + carPlate3.getState() + " " + carPlate3.getColor());

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream text = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("dataOutput.txt", false));

        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(text);

        pw.println(writeCarPlate1);
        pw.println(writeCarPlate2);
        pw.println(writeCarPlate3);
        pw.flush();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Writer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Writer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

}
```

Please note that I know that the `InputStream` imports are unused right now, I plan to use them later on in the program, and I have tried commenting them out and running the program again, though it does not make any difference.

And just in case it is relevant, here is the code from the `CarPlate` class that defines the `CarPlate` object:

```
public class CarPlate {
    private String number;
    private String state;
    private String color;

    public CarPlate() {

    }

    public CarPlate(String number, String state, String color) {
        this.number = number;
        this.state = state;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Finally, here is the output of the text file:

> ¨Ì�w01098463 CA Blue
>
> 6371849 MA Red
>
> 5738402 AZ Green

I simply want the text file to be:

> 01098463 CA Blue
>
> 6371849 MA Red
>
> 5738402 AZ Green

I really appreciate any help, thanks guys!

Comment: @user2494817 that should be an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are using an ObjectOutputStream, which prepends certain information into the file:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html

Just use a PrintWriter or FileOutputStream to write to the file, unless you are trying to write the objects...

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new File("dataoutput.txt"));
```

Answer (score -2):

don't use FileOutputStream to write in files instead of that try using

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( yourfilename));
writer.write( yourstring);
```

Comment: if you want save the state of the object, you must use ObjectOutputStream   to serialize the object to the file you want.

if you want put simple readable text you can use just FiletOutputStream .

if you have unreadable text with strange charset with special characters , i think using bufferedWriter is the best way in this stage.